# MS-SQL-Server 2019 is slower than SQL-Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2019

Since we updated from SQL Server 2008 to 2019, the queries have become much slower.

The following query ran for ten minutes on version 2008. On version 2019 it runs for over 30 minutes.

Until yesterday, we always limited the WHERE-clause: where date > '20180101'

To make the script at least a bit faster, I narrowed it down from January 2019: where date > '20190101'

Now it's even slower than before. No joke! Because one year less has to be evaluated, the running time has increased by a few minutes.

I have checked all the indexes in detail and I think we have created the correct indexes.
But I don't know if this is really an index problem, because in version 2008 we had the same indexes.
In version 2019 I even deleted and re-created a few important indexes. But that didn't help at all.

MS-SQL Server 2019 got very slow and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you updated statistics for all the databases after moving to SQL Server 2019 ?. You might be facing what we call as [CE regression](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2014/03/17/the-new-and-improved-cardinality-estimator-in-sql-server-2014/). What is compatibility level of databases moved 100 or 150 ?

Comment: A consultant moved the database from version 2008 to 2019. I don't know whether the statistics have been updated. How can I do that?

Comment: I see a **lot** of warnings like "Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,[Salamander_DWH].[dbo].[F_BonusSWDS].[gueltig_ab],0)) may affect "Cardinality Estimate" in query plan choice.", mouse over the first block in paste the plan.

Comment: The compatibility level of our databases are: SQL Server 2008 (100)

Comment: I found the statistics in the tables. Do I have to manually click and update every statistic in the SSMS?

Comment: Yes, we actually have different date fields. Some date fields only consist of strings.

Comment: sp_updatestats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-updatestats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
This does use resources, so maybe off hours?  This is most likely a band-aid until you can test Compat level, etc.

Comment: @SipCat Please include all the additional info in the comments to the question.

Comment: There's an old saying that when you have issues with performance regarding the CE level, then you likely have issues with the query to being with. and the fact that you had decent performance earlier was just luck. Or something like that. Joining over a CONVERT is an immediate thing that sticks out. First step is to compare the plan between the old and the new. Running with old CE should give you same plan shape, but you never know. And then probably treat this as any type of performance tuning work. I.e., clean-up the query, work the plan, indexes etc.

Comment: It's running minutes or seconds? The attached execution plan finishes in a minute, half of which is spent doing insert itslef. Sounds like a storage problem at least partially?

Comment: OK you got 13 tables to join, no clustered indexes, if you have NC indexes they are not being used, 1.2m rows, joins and grouping on converted columns, the insert target is a heap with 4 NCIs. I'm not sure how you ever expected this query to run in any reasonable amount of time in its current setup. You probably just lucked out on the old CE. I'd also love to know what the point of that `TOP 100 PERCENT` is.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "TOP 100 Percent" means. These queries are all from an outside consultant, and I left them as they are. In the past, this solution has worked great, even if it looks ugly.

Comment: On the SQL Server 2008, these queries ran in 10 minutes. These queries run in 30 minutes on the SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Lots of people talking about no indexes on underlying tables... this is true, and not ideal - but the query plan shows the SELECT part of the query is a fraction of the overall cost. It's the INSERT to the destination table and its 3 indexes taking up resources.

Answer (score 3):

The database compatibility level controls the behavior of the query optimizer.

So the recommended upgrade process is to keep the upgraded database on the lower database compatibility level initially, while you use Query Store to capture a performance baseline for the database.

See

[image]

[Change the Database Compatibility Level and use the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3):

From the query plan you provided it runs a minute:

[image]

But it compiles 33 minutes (1992254 ms ~= 1992 s ~= 60 * 33 = 33 minutes):

[image]

So basically you had a problem on 2008 already. It's just exaggerated in 2019. Never experienced such an extreme case in my life, but I would try to simplify the views you are using and drop not used indexes on underlying tables. Or maybe split the query: first select view into temp table and then use the temp table in your original query.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your query execution plan it doesn't look like you database contains any indexes or they where disabled during/by the migration process.

Based on the statement in your question:

> With this join, I create an index on the F_Skonto table with the three columns gueltig_ab, gueltig_bis and CD_Kunde. Is that correct?

...I'm not sure if you are aware of what an index is. The answer to your question is:

**No, a JOIN does not create an index. A JOIN can cause an existing index to be used to speed up the query.**

Your statement may have been based on your knowledge of the English language and thus be misleading. I'll asume you know that an index is basically a Table of Contents that the the SQL Server Database Engine can use to speed up queries by knowing where to look for the data.

In that case we may be looking at the possible issue that the indexes are all disabled. If an index is disable it can't be use for speeding up queries.

Execute the following query to see if you have indexes which have been disalbed:

```
SELECT s.name                  AS Schema_name,
       o.name                  AS Table_Name,
       i.name                  AS Index_Name,
       i.is_disabled           AS Index_Disabled
FROM   sys.objects             AS o
       JOIN sys.schemas        AS s
            ON  s.schema_id = o.schema_id
       JOIN sys.indexes        AS i
            ON  i.object_id = o.object_id
        JOIN sys.sysindexes as si
                   ON  si.[id] = i.object_id
            AND si.indid = i.index_id
WHERE  1=1 
       AND s.name != 'sys'           -- Exclude sys items
       AND i.is_disabled = 1         -- Show only disabled indexes
ORDER BY
1,2,3
```

This will produce a similar output to this:

> ```
> +----------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
> |  Schema_name   | Table_Name |     Index_Name     | Index_Disabled |
> +----------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
> | HumanResources | Department | AK_Department_Name |              1 |
> +----------------+------------+--------------------+----------------+
> ```

If any indexes have been disabled in your tables, then you will receive a list. With this list you can then go ahead and rebuild the indexes which will enable them again and which might result in a faster `SELECT` part of your `INSERT` statement.

If no disabled indexes are returned by the above statement, then we will check if you have any indexes at all by running the same statement without the `AND i.is_disabled = 1` part.

Like this:

```
SELECT s.name                  AS Schema_name,
       o.name                  AS Table_Name,
       i.name                  AS Index_Name,
       i.is_disabled           AS Index_Disabled
FROM   sys.objects             AS o
       JOIN sys.schemas        AS s
            ON  s.schema_id = o.schema_id
       JOIN sys.indexes        AS i
            ON  i.object_id = o.object_id
        JOIN sys.sysindexes as si
            ON  si.[id] = i.object_id
            AND si.indid = i.index_id
WHERE  1=1 
       AND s.name != 'sys'           -- Exclude sys items
ORDER BY
1,2,3
```

In my **AdventureWorks2012** database provided by Microsoft, this will produce a list which looks like this:

> ```
> +----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> |  Schema_name   |        Table_Name        |                   Index_Name                   | Index_Disabled |
> +----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> | dbo            | AWBuildVersion           | PK_AWBuildVersion_SystemInformationID          |              0 |
> | dbo            | DatabaseLog              | NULL                                           |              0 |
> | dbo            | DatabaseLog              | PK_DatabaseLog_DatabaseLogID                   |              0 |
> | dbo            | ErrorLog                 | PK_ErrorLog_ErrorLogID                         |              0 |
> | dbo            | ufnGetContactInformation | NULL                                           |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Department               | AK_Department_Name                             |              1 |
> | HumanResources | Department               | PK_Department_DepartmentID                     |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | AK_Employee_LoginID                            |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | AK_Employee_NationalIDNumber                   |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | AK_Employee_rowguid                            |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | IX_Employee_OrganizationLevel_OrganizationNode |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | IX_Employee_OrganizationNode                   |              0 |
> | HumanResources | Employee                 | PK_Employee_BusinessEntityID                   |              0 |
> ```

If the above statement does not provide any output, then your tables don't have any indexes. We will have to start creating some...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Yes, I know what an index is, but my English is not really good. The phrase with the join was poorly worded.

Comment: I tried the first Select from you, but no disabled indexes are displayed.

Comment: I tried the second Select from you, and now indexes are displayed, but each table also has a NULL index (I added a hard copy above). Is the NULL index an error?

Comment: It seems to me that my indexes are all being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true there are no indexes on the underlying tables, the query plan shows the vast majority of resources are being used for the insert to the destination table and its 3 indexes.

One way to improve performance of large/ bulk inserts is to disable indexes prior to the insert and rebuild them after.
If you have a unique clustered primary key (or unique index(es)) you could keep them as non-clustered constraints for the INSERT to ensure validation rules are maintained if you're not confident data being inserted will be valid.

Following the INSERT, drop these temp versions (if used) and rebuild original indexes.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the query setting up the **legacy cardinalty extimation** (ON):

[image]

as a second test try to turn on **Query optimizer fixes** (ON)

Comment: My "Database Scoped Configurations" looks exactly like in your hard copy. Which option should I adjust?

Comment: I think the suggestion to toggle the top option in the Database Scoped Configurations, Legacy Cardinality Estimation, to ON.

Comment: exactly. the other one is "Query optimizer Fixes". try the first one, then the second one, then both

Comment: I've tried both options, but that didn't improve performance. Do I have to restart the database for the options to take effect, or do the new options take effect immediately after the change in the SSMS?

Comment: it is immediate. so your problem is not related to the cardinality extimation

Answer (score 0):

As per your execution plan shared on Brent's paste the plan, I can only see table scan happening. If you say your indexes are in place, I doubt they are online or being used. You should start your investigation from there.

Comment: I also have my doubts whether my indexes are all set up correctly. But I always use the columns from the JOIN for this. I've given an example of this as a separate answer.

Comment: If the term "table scan" appears in the execution plan, is that an indication of a "full table scan", and that means that no index has been used here?

Comment: Yes. It indicates a full table scan and the index is not used or doesn't exist.