# upgraded the database from 2012 to 2016 and specific query runs slow

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016

I successfully restored a database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. Now some queries are running slow.

Especially this one.

```
SELECT * 
From DayCalDupLocGradeDayVW A  
Where A.DistCode = 'NY660900' 
  AND A.SchoolYear = '2022-06-30' 
  AND Exists 
    (Select 1 
     From DayCalDupLocGradeDayVW B 
     Where a.DistCode=b.DistCode 
       AND A.SchoolYear=B.SchoolYear 
       AND A.SchoolDate=B.SchoolDate 
       AND A.LocProgCode=B.LocProgCode 
       AND A.GRADE_LEVEL=B.GRADE_LEVEL 
       AND A.DayType <> B.DayType
    )
```

When I pass the `SchoolYear` as 2022 it works fine. I cannot change the query, as it's part of a legacy application. This query works fine in SQL Server 2012. I tried setting the compatibility to low and legacy cardinality to ON, but this was of no help.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I suggest you add the CREATE TABLE statement and the query execution plan.

Comment: Have you changed compatibility level to 2016? If yes try to move it back to 2012.

Comment: Also: does `SchoolYear` column have values like `'2022-06-30'` and like `'2022'`? That seems odd.

Comment: `DayCalDupLocGradeDayVW` This is a view? If so, you need to consider that code as well.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: In SQL Server, `2022` would be an accepted form of specifying the date of `2022-01-01` or the timestamp of `2022-01-01T00:00:00`.

Comment: @AndriyM thnx, didn't know that. But the table seems to have both a `SchoolYear` and a `SchoolDate` column, so I was wondering for that, and also what datatype are these columns. Akila?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: It may be unclear from my comment so I'd like to clarify just to remove any possible doubt: for that to work, the value should be specified as a string literal, so `'2022'`, not just `2022`, and the column/expression the value is compared to (or the variable it's assigned to) needs to be a date/datetime/smalldatetime/datetime2/datetimeoffset one.

Comment: @AndriyM you are missed from the Heap ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Microsoft's guidelines as explained in [Upgrade SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs).

This starter document contains steps to other documents.

There is a sub document named [Upgrade Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs) which contains a **Step 4.** which applies to your situation, because you are **upgrading** - via the backup and restore process - **a database from one version to another**.

Step 4. explains:

> Upgrade the **[Database Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15#compatibility-levels-and-database-engine-upgrades)** (Applies to: SQL Server and Azure SQL Database). One of the steps to take after your databases are online in the new version of SQL Server or Azure SQL Database, may be to upgrade the databases functionality mode to enable new features, by changing the database compatibility level. This can be done manually or through the Query Tuning Assistant.

Clicking on the link (**[Database Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15#compatibility-levels-and-database-engine-upgrades)**) takes you to the `ALTER DATABASE...` documentation, which has a section explaining:

> **Compatibility levels and Database Engine upgrades**
> Database Compatibility Level is a valuable tool to assist in database modernization, by allowing the SQL Server Database Engine to be upgraded, while keeping connecting applications functional status **by maintaining the same pre-upgrade Database Compatibility Level.** This means that it is possible to upgrade from an older version of SQL Server (such as SQL Server 2008) to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database (including Managed Instance) with no application changes (except for database connectivity). For more information, see Compatibility Certification.
>
> As long as the application does not need to leverage enhancements that are only available in a higher Database Compatibility Level, **it is a valid approach to upgrade the SQL Server Database Engine and maintain the previous Database Compatibility Level.** For more information on using compatibility level for backward compatibility, see Compatibility Certification.

#### Answering Your Observation

> I successfully restored a database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016. Now some queries are running slow.

You might have to change the Database Compatibility Level either up or down depending on the level of your restored database to achieve better performance.

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
```

This will tell the SQL Server engine to treat your database as if it were running on a SQL Server 2012 instance.

If your database is already running in the compatibility level for SQL Server 2012 which can be queried via:

```
SELECT dbs.name, dbs.compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;
```

...then try switching to the new compatibility level:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130;
```

There are a lot of other settings and trace flags that could assist you in combatting your issues. However, I would recommend consulting a consultant for in-depth analysis or providing more details as suggested in the comments.

#### Additional Resources

The answer to the question [MS-SQL-Server 2019 is slower than SQL-Server 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/286054/15356) goes into some Microsoft recommendations on how to migrate a database.

[image: Picture of recommended migration steps]

- Upgrade to latest SQL Server
- Enable Query Store
- Collect data on workload (Baseline)
- Set DB compatibility level to latest
- Fix regressions by forcing good execution plans